# Redirigir del .es al .com con nginx y certbot

Tags: nginx, redirección, certificado-ssl

Buenas noches no consigo hacer que el .es redirija directamente al .com.

Utilizo nginx, certbot y como framework Laravel 8.0.

Cuando entro en mi dominio .es me sale la app pero no me redirije al .com y el .com si que abre mi app sin problemas.

En mi panel he realizado el apunte de los dos dominios a mi servidor, pero no hay forma.

Este es mi archivo .conf:

```
server {
    server_name dominio.es www.dominio.es dominio.com www.dominio.com;
    

   root /var/www/miapp/public;

   add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
   add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

   index index.html index.htm index.php;

   charset utf-8;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
   }

   location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
   location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

   error_page 404 /index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }

   location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
      deny all;
   }




    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/miapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/miapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}

server {
    if ($host = www.dominio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = dominio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.dominio.es) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = dominio.es) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name dominio.es www.dominio.es dominio.com www.dominio.com;

    
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno di con la solución, no se si es la más apropiada, si alguien tiene una mejor solución estaria encantado de aprenderla.

```
if ($host = www.dominio.com) {
  return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = dominio.com) {
  return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = www.dominio.es) {
  return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = dominio.es) {
   return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

Hay que hacer el return 301 así: `return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;`